# Display old data using Socket.io in a particular room

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have created a Room in my Application. When a new user joins, how can I display them the old content that had been sent. Taking array is not working because it works globally(for all the rooms) and when I declare the array inside the connection function, the data is not being displayed.

Comment: How do you identify rooms?

Comment: with the pathname in  URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can modify your solution that "works globally" so that it works per-room.

I guess you did something like this:

```
// At the beginning:
const messages = [];

// When a user joins,
// you send the 'messages' history

// When a user sends a message:
const newMessage = {username: 'Stratubas', body: 'Hello!', timestamp: Date.now()};
messages.push(newMessage);
```

so you can modify it to something like this:

```
// At the beginning:
const messagesPerRoom = {};

// When a user joins a room:
const roomId = 'the_url_parameter_value';
if (messagesPerRoom[roomId] === undefined) {
  messagesPerRoom[roomId] = [];
}
// and send the 'messagesPerRoom[roomId]' history

// When a user sends a message:
const newMessage = {username: 'Stratubas', body: 'Hello!', timestamp: Date.now()};
messagesPerRoom[roomId].push(newMessage);
```